# How to include an SVG file in HTML5 so that xlinks behave like inline?

Tags: html, svg

I like to embed SVG in HTML, but prefer to have the files separated, just because I tend to edit HTML and SVG in different editors.

However, when I try to use `<object>`, the behaviour is different from inline. Links inside the SVG (such as `<a xlink:href="http://stackoverflow.com/">...</a>`) let the browser (FF38 here) open the page only in the object area. I like the normal inline behaviour, which is like HTML.

I tried `<img>`, but then links in the SVG don't work at all. I also tried `<embed>` and `<iframe>`, but it seems to do the same as `<object>` only worse.

So far, I can only imagine server side (templates) or client side (JavaScript) merging. Any other options?

Comment: Have you tried adding `target="_parent"`?

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, at least for `<object>`!